# How to have a slide in animation that moves other views as the slide happens

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to have a LinearLayout View change from View.GONE to View.Visible when a button is pressed. I want it to slide down from underneath the button and as it slides, it pushed the other Views down (and vice-versa). What happens now is the height of the View to be shown appears as empty space and all the other Views are immediately lower, and then notesListView slides down from the top of the space that just appeared.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

```
        notesButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (notesListView.isShown()) {
              iconView.setScaleY(-1);
                Animation aniSlide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.slide_up);
                notesListView.startAnimation(aniSlide);

                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(() -> notesListView.setVisibility(View.GONE), 1000);

            } else {
                iconView.setScaleY(1);

                notesListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Animation aniSlide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.slide_down);
                notesListView.startAnimation(aniSlide);
            }
        });
```

I've tried every tutorial and SO post on this that I can find but they all do the same thing.